# Why am I seeing 404 error when trying to edit a user?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to spring boot and thymeleaf. I have a list of users that is displayed in a table and next to each user there's an edit button that is supposed to open that user's details in a pre-populated form that can be updated. However when I click on the edit button I don't see the form, instead, I'm presented with the 404 not found error.

This is the table that displays the Users:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><i class="icon_profile"></i> Firstname</th>
                <th><i class="icon_profile"></i>Lastname</th>
                <th><i class="icon_profile"></i>Username</th>
                <th><i class="icon_profile"></i>Roles</th>
                <th></th>
                <th><i class="icon_cogs"></i> Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="user:${users}">
                <td th:text="${user.firstname}">Firstname</td>
                <td th:text="${user.lastname}">Lastname</td>
                <td th:text="${user.username}">Username</td>
                <td th:text="${user.roles}">Roles</td>
                <td><a th:href="@{'/user/Edit/'+${user.id}}">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The method in controller that's supposed to open the edit page:

```
@GetMapping("/users/edit/{id}")
    public String editUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        User user = userService.get(id);
        List<Role> listRoles = userService.listRoles();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("listRoles", listRoles);
        return "user_form";
    }
```

**Add new User**

```
@PostMapping(value="users/addNew")
    public RedirectView addNew(User user, RedirectAttributes redirect, Model model) throws QrGenerationException {//Controller used to add new user to database(Register new user)
        userService.save(user);
        RedirectView  redirectView= new RedirectView("/login",true);//After successful registration user is redirected to the login page
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("message",   "You successfully registered! You can now login");
        return redirectView;
    }
```

**UserService**

```
public void save(User user){
        Role roleUser = roleRepository.findByName("User");
        user.addRole(roleUser);//Gives each new user a default role: User
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

What am I missing?

When I click on the edit button on a specific user, a form should be opened with the data of that user in the fields

Comment: The Thymeleaf expression `th:href="@{'/user/Edit/'+${user.id}}"` looks as if it will generate the URL `/user/Edit/...` whereas your controller's method is expecting `"/users/edit/..."`. So `user` does not equal `users` and `Edit` does not equal `edit`.

Comment: Also, this is not the best Thymeleaf syntax to use to build a parameterized URL with `@{...}` (does it even work?). See [the documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#link-urls).

Comment: @andrewJames Thanks I didn't even think to look at that.